# Relative pronouns (where vs. which)

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

A relative clause always contains a relative pronoun, as we all know, it depends on the subject of our sentence if it's a thing or a person, or if it contains a possessive adjective, etc...
While I was practicing that, I found a problem with these two sentences:

> The point of view is clear. The material discrepancy appears in it.

(use the suitable relative pronoun to connect these sentences)

If you try to use which, then the sentence will be:

> The point of view, which the material discrepancy appears in, is clear

Notice that I omitted *it*)

But when I think again of using another relative pronoun, which is *where*, then I have to omit *in* and *it*:

> The point of view,where the material discrepancy appears, is clear.

And my questions are:

- Is it correct to use where in this sentence (since I feel the meaning is still clear?
- If I use the last, have I to omit both *in* and *it*?
- Which is more accurate to use: where or which?

another sentence:

> Do you mind showing me the place? You live in it.

- Do you mind showing me the place where you live?
- Do you mind showing me the place which you live in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Where* and *when*, either as interrogatives or as relatives, are not pronouns but pro-adverbs—they ‘stand for’ adverbials of place and time, respectively.

> The place *where* I found it = the place *at/in which* I found it
>   *Where* did you find it? = *At/in what place* did you find it?
>   The time *when* I found it = the time *at which* I found it
>   *When* did you find it? = *At what time* did you find it?

It is thus not strictly true to say that “a relative clause always contains a relative pronoun”—it may also be headed by a relative pro-adverb. And in some cases (as in *He told me to stop, which I did*) the relative ‘pronoun’ is actually a component of a relative pro-verbal construction with *DO*.

Comment: :I really want to get a clear answer about what I exactly want.The usage of which and where:Is it possible(or always to say)that every sentence contains (in it)can be connected with the other by where or which as I mentioned in the examples above??

Comment: @user55891 You can use *where* for *in which* only if the *in* expresses a (literal or figurative) place or direction. You should not, for instance, paraphrase *The plot **in which** he was implicated* as *The plot **where** he was implicated*.

Comment: What do you mean with expresses a figurative??

Comment: @user55891 For instance, a book is a figurative location - it is fine to say "*The Birth of Tragedy*, **where** Nietzsche sets forth the contrast between the Dionysiac and the Appolonian ..."

Comment: Aherm. Pro-adverb? Pro-preposition, surely?!

Comment: @Araucaria This was written in the early days of sorting out my take in these matters. Today I'd fudge and call *where* and *when* "locatives"; I'm inching closer to stating flatly that that makes them not "pro-prepositions" but *"pro-PPs"*. HOWEVER: that only defines the internal structure; it leaves open the external syntactic role of the locative, which is iffy here--is it an adverbial (modifier of the verb or the VP or clause) or is it some sort of locative complement of the verb--or is it a predication on the object of the verb? You tell me!

Comment: @StoneyB But pronouns are pro-NPs, not pro-nouns. So by extension wouldn't we want proprepositions not pro-PPs. Erm, re your question, everything's screwy in some of the OP's examples because of the antecedent *place*, [which has an exceptional effect on relative clauses](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/290864/is-it-possible-to-leave-out-the-relative-pronoun-where/290866#290866). Erm, so *I* don't know!

Comment: @Araucaria Hmm ... think I'll stick with "prolocative" for the time being. Or perhaps I'll go back to Ælfric and call it a "foresetness player".